# In Google Sheets, I want to get all data from a specific column where the first column matches my SKU. There are multiple rows with that SKU

Tags: google-sheets

I have data that looks like this:

| sku | price | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab1 | 1.01 | 1 |
| ab2 | 2.06 | 1 |
| ab2 | 1.45 | 25 |
| ab3 | 2.00 | 1 |
| ab3 | 1.40 | 10 |
| ab3 | 0.89 | 25 |
| ac2 | 0.74 | 1 |
| ac2 | 0.50 | 100 |

As you can see, I have products that have quantity discounts in one sheet. I need to get these levels and prices out of this sheet and into another sheet.

**I need to get all prices and levels for all skus, not just the first match. So if my lookup is for sku AB3 I would expect to find 2.00 / 1, 1.40 / 10 and 0.89 / 25**

I have not got an extensive Google Sheets knowledge so I am afraid I have hit a brick wall in what to search for.

What do I need to do in order to get this data from sheet a into sheet b.

I have not yet decided how this data is going to look in sheet b, so I don't know if I want the price and level to go into the same cell like "1.01 per 25" or in separate cells.

Comment: What result do you want from given dataset?

Comment: I'll edit my post.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(B2:C,A2:A=F1)
```

Or `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY(A2:C,"select B, C where A='" & F1 & "'")
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to use the following but I am getting an error: "=QUERY(vlookup(A2,importrange("LINK-TO-MY-SHEET","A:S"),9,false),"select F, G where A='" & A2 & "'")"

Comment: You do not need `VLOOKUP()` and when you are using `IMPORTRANGE()` then query statement will be like `select Col2, Col3 where Col1='" & A2 & "'")`.